# Macros in YYYYMMDDHHMISS format

Tags: airflow

**Requirement:**

Get the date value in the format of `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`

**Code:**

```
TS_HOURS_NODASH = "{{ execution_date.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }}"
```

**Output**

```
20200721000000
```

**Expected**: Actual hour/minute/seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved using `pendulum`

`pendulum.now().format('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on that you need:

- execution_date - it is a time when your dag expected to run. In case your dag run on a `@daily` basis your time will be exactly 00:00:00
- ti.start_date - it is a time when your task instance actually started.

Comment: I needed to get that format to append to the filename

Answer (score 0):

`execution_date` is calculated according to schedule interval, execution_date of all task instances related to the dag run is the same, and it is **not** the actual datetime that a task is run.

if you just want to get the actual start time of the task, why not get the system time at the beginning of your task, although it is slightly later than airflow task's start_time, it is much easier.

if you insist on the start_time of airflow, it needs to do some change on the operator, and it is another story.

usually, it is better to use execution_date as suffix of a file, it is stable and will not change after the task instance is generated, the actual start time of a task depends on the upstream tasks, retry also change start time, and it will also change if your clear some task instances and re-run them.